# Changing Path variable

Tags: linux, bash, path

I am not able to permanently change my PATH variable.
I tried changing .bash_profile file but, the changes were reverted (however the .bash_profile file had the path which I wrote) when I closed the terminal.

Comment: Is your `~/.bash_profile` or `~/.bashrc` file ever _resetting_ the `PATH` variable (i.e. setting it without using its old value)?  It's difficult to help since we can't see your files.

Comment: It is unclear what you did, show us what you did.